# How to focus input element in html in React popup behaviour

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a React Typescript app and when the user clicks a button, they should be prompted with a model dialog that asks them for a comment. I would like the textbox input control of this modal to be focussed when they click the button, so they can start typing straight away - but can't figure out how to do that. Can anyone suggest?

Also as a second question - is there a way I can bind the "Enter" keystroke to close the modal? Escape is built in as a special behaviour character in NPM react-modal but I would like Enter to submit the OK button.

My react modal component (using NPM react-modal)

```
 <ReactModal 
    isOpen={this.state.dialogOpen}
    contentLabel="Example Modal"
    className="Modal"
    overlayClassName="Overlay"
    shouldCloseOnEsc={true}
    shouldReturnFocusAfterClose={true}
    role="dialog"
    onRequestClose={this.handleCloseModal}
    shouldCloseOnOverlayClick={false}
    // tslint:disable
    parentSelector={() => document.body}
  > 
  <div className="Modal-Container">
      <div style={{flex:0.4}}>
        <div className="Panel-header-left">
          Please enter a reason for rejecting
        </div>
      </div>
      <div style={{flex:0.6}}>
        <input type="textbox" name="ModalInput" value={this.state.comment} onChange={ this.handleCommentChange.bind(this)} />
      </div>
      <div>
        <div className="Panel-header-right">
          <button className="Action-Button" onClick={(e) => this.handleCloseModal()}>Cancel</button>
          <button className="Action-Button" onClick={(e) => this.processRejectComments()}>OK</button>
        </div>
      </div>          
  </div>
  </ReactModal>
```

and my button click to load the modal

```
private doReject()
  {
    if (this.gridApi.getSelectedNodes().length > 0)
    {
      this.setState({comment: ""});
      this.handleOpenModal();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. To focus the input of the modal**, first set reference of `<input>` then call `input.focus()` in `onAfterOpen()` of `react-modal`

```
<ReactModal 
  isOpen={this.state.dialogOpen}
  onAfterOpen={() => this._input.focus()}
>
  <input ref={input => this._input = input}/>
</ReactModal>
```

**2. To close modal on user press Enter**, wrap the `<input>` by a `<form>`, then close model in its `onSubmit()`

```
<ReactModal
  isOpen={this.state.dialogOpen}
>
  <form onSubmit={() => this.setState({dialogOpen: false})>
    <input {...} />
  </form>
</ReactModal>
```

Here's CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/wn18lvjlx7